# Sane stopped detecting USB scanner

Tags: linux, usb, scanner, multi-function-printer, sane

My scanner (scanner function of the MX860 multifunction printer) was being recognized using the `sane-find-scanner` command or using `scanimage -L`. It was working with Simple Scan, the `scanimage` utility, and `sane-backend` (with C++). All of a sudden it stopped working -- the device is not recognized by sane on Linux anymore.

I'm using a dual-boot Lubuntu 18.04/Windows 10. Windows 10 still recognizes the scanner.

It happened when I was using `sane-backend` in C++, but I'm not sure how this could have caused the error-- I don't think the code could have broken the recognition of the scanner. The printer is definitely supported by sane, and it is securely connected to power and connected via USB cable to my computer.

If you think it may be the culprit, here's the C++ code. It reads from the scanner and saves the data into a PNM image file. It was working fine until the `outFile.open()` suddenly began to return the status of `Invalid argument`, which is when `scanimage -L` stopped recognizing the scanner.

```
unsigned char data[50000];
int maxLength = 50000;
int length;

std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("./out/test.pnm");

SANE_Handle handle;
SANE_Parameters parm;
SANE_Status openStatus = sane_open("pixma:04A91735_10C369", &handle);
SANE_Status paramStatus = sane_get_parameters(handle, &parm);
SANE_Status startStatus = sane_start(handle);
SANE_Status readStatus;

// write header of PNM file
outFile << "P6\n# SANE data follows\n" << parm.pixels_per_line << " " << parm.lines << "\n" << ((parm.depth <= 8) ? 255 : 65535) << "\n";

do {
  readStatus = sane_read(handle, data, maxLength, &length);
  outFile.write((const char *) data, length);
} while(readStatus == SANE_STATUS_GOOD);
sane_close(handle);
outFile.close();

// debugging
std::cout << sane_strstatus(openStatus) << std::endl;
std::cout << sane_strstatus(paramStatus) << std::endl;
std::cout << sane_strstatus(startStatus) << std::endl;
std::cout << sane_strstatus(readStatus) << " " << length << std::endl;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The first port of call is to see if any updates or new configurations broke it - first see if its recognised _at all_ using `lsusb` (might want to run `lsusb | grep MX860` to save time) and if it does recognise it, then try a live Linux USB to see if sane works there. If so, you probably broke it with a new configuration of sorts - if it shows up in lsusb then you know Linux sees it, but Sane doesn't.

Comment: `lsusb` gives `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04a9:1735 Canon, Inc.`, so it is recognized by Linux, and the printing function still works when connected by USB. Does that indicate anything to you?

Comment: Good idea with the live USB -- I'll try that.

Comment: That's a good sign - the USB device interfaces correctly with Linux still, and confirmed with the printer working. It seems from here the mismatch is between sane and the scanner device. If you haven't saved anything of value to the sane libraries/config, then perhaps try to reinstall sane and see if it fixes it to as it was. A liveUSB further tests whether sane works as it should have a "vanilla" config.

Comment: @QuickishFM I don't have a liveUSB on hand but I tried purging the sane libraries and reinstalling them (`scanimage` comes with the OS, though, so I didn't remove that). Still no luck. May burn a liveUSB soon to try

Comment: If you have the computer power to virtualise another OS, then you could also  run a live USB iso in Virtualbox and pass through the USB device for the printer/scanner and test it that way. I suspect it may still be a settings issue so I'm thinking the bad config might have been saved across reinstalls - check for anything involving sane in your `.config` folder or your home folder. Then rename it and reboot, if might fix the issue.

Comment: @QuickishFM I solved it some time later, but I'm not sure why the solution wasn't necessary when it was working before this problem appeared.

Comment: i ran into this issue and rebooting the computer fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this out a few hours later. In the output of `scanimage -L` there was the following text:

```
# No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
# the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.
# SANE has been built without libusb support. This may be a reason
# for not detecting USB scanners. Read README for more details.
```

I installed `libusb` (`apt install libusb-1.0-0-dev`) and re-made `sane-backends` (`./configure && make && sudo make install` in the sane-backends directory).

This solved the problem. However, I don't know why the script worked in the first place without `libusb` installed before.

Comment: did you have to build anything from source to begin with?  i'm not following why this should even be necessary